# Formatting regex in Dart on several lines

Tags: regex, dart

I have

```
Pattern pattern = r'^((?:19|20)\d\d)[- /.]
(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$';
```

My editor shows an error on this regexp:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew dart

Comment: It compiles well in Dart. What is the issue? Please add the full relevant code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew look at this https://i.ibb.co/b3nVcVC/Untitled-1.jpg

Comment: You placed a newline inside the pattern, why? If you need to split the pattern into several lines use `r'...'  + r'...'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks that was the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You entered a line break inside a string literal, that is why you get a syntax issue.

If you want to split a pattern into several lines, just use string concatenation:

```
Pattern pattern = r'^((?:19|20)\d\d)[- /.]' +
    r'(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$';
```

Or, since string literals separated only with whitespace characters are concatenated automatically:

```
Pattern pattern = r'^((?:19|20)\d\d)[- /.]'
    r'(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$';
```

Or, if you plan to re-use a long pattern, you may define this part as a  variable, and just use string interpolation:

```
String d = r'((?:19|20)\d\d)';
String M = r'(0[1-9]|1[012])';
String y = r'(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])';
String sep = r'[- /.]';
Pattern pattern = '^$d$sep$M$sep$y\$';
```

Comment: You can also skip the `+` – adjacent string literals auto-magically concat!